# How do I expose integration actions via Notion API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notion-api, notion

I'm building a Chrome extension that will leverage the Notion API through an integration. Part of this extension requires users enter OAuth flows for different platforms.

I would like to create a menu within Notion for my users, accessible through an integration action. However, I cannot find any documentation on how to expose my extensions actions to Notion. I've seen other integrations achieve it, and it grants access to an icon like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3roi.png) Usually, the context menu opened from this has a settings row as well as a feedback row, each opening up to their own individual pages.

I can't think of any way to do this other than injecting the DOM elements myself, there must be a better way. It would make sense for there to be an endpoint where we could build the pages ourselves via API, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

I've scoured the [documentation](https://developers.notion.com/reference/intro) up and down to no avail, besides CRUDing notion pages and databases. I'm completely blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is no way to create custom menus or actions within the Notion app, you can only interact with the API with the available endpoints in the documentation.

Other apps that do it are injecting DOM elements directly.